# Regex to extract placenames containing 'of' (like 'Isle of Man') when text also contains 'of'

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have some historical text that contains text descriptions such as 'Son of Mrs. H. E. Tyler, of Chester Lodge, Epsom, Surrey'

I have a regex `/.* of .*,? of (.*)/` which works fine, until there is a valid use of the word 'of' within a placename. So for the above example it returns 'Chester Lodge, Epsom, Surrey' but for 'Son of Mrs. H. E. Tyler, of Chester Lodge, Sandown, Isle of Wight' it returns simply 'Wight', not 'Chester Lodge, Sandown, Isle of Wight'

How can I construct a regex such that if the 'of' is in the context 'Isle of .*' it places the entire placename in the capture string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the valid `of` locations always occur at the end of the string, then all you need to do is to make the repetition of the characters *lazy* instead of *greedy*, so they'll start at the shortest length possible and increment longer until a match is found, rather than starting at the longest length possible and incrementing shorter:

```
.*? of .*?,? of (.*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/INAuLy/1

(as long as you don't have any *actual names* that include `" of "`, should be fine)

Comment: That works, thank you!  I do have some entries with trailing text, but I have a combination of expressions/code that already split and clean the string (e.g. for 'Son of John E. and Emma Caws, of Dudley House, Sea View, Isle of Wight; husband of Sarah A. Wilkes (formerly Caws), of 45, Westbourne St., Walsall, Staffs.' I split it on the ';' to capture both addresses) so I think it's pretty much sorted, thanks